# How to make libcurl look in the Mac Keychain for certificates

Tags: macos, security, https, libcurl, keychain

My code is trying to access an HTTPS server and it has its own certificate. Example, the IP is "10.0.1.101".

If I go through Safari and access "http://10.0.1.101", everything's OK. I do a simple curl_easy_perform() for this URL and data can be pulled from the HTTP URL. Cool.

I then try to access "https://10.0.1.101" (yes, HTTPS) and from Safari, I accept the certificate and give it a "trust" option and after that, Safari access to the HTTPS URL is OK.

So the certificate has been added to the Mac Keychain but when I try a curl_easy_perform() on the HTTPS URL, it still returns with a CURLE_SSL_CACERT. libcurl could not authenticate the HTTPS certificate with known CA certificates.

What is the missing link between libcurl's certificate checking and Mac Keychain? Is there even a link at all? Is it possible to make libcurl look into the Mac Keychain for certificates? If so, how?

Comment: Can we use CURLOPT_CAINFO option to point to a keychain file?

Comment: There's a `security` command in terminal, I think you can use the output of that command to get the trust chain. (I'm not a certificate or terminal expert, tried in a script and it works with curl)

Comment: @Marcelo Alves, thanks. It looks like a good starting point but if you can, will you share the steps how you did it?

Comment: I've tried "security add-trusted-cert PathToPEMFile.pem" on both user and system keychain but libcurl still fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. libcurl built to use OpenSSL will only read CA certs from a single PEM file or from a directory of CA certs that have been prepared OpenSSL-style.

There's no special magic for the Mac Keychain implemented.

Comment: Really? Well then, this is *weird*.  My machine running Mountain Lion "just works" and recognizes the cert fine, but my machine running Yosemite is *no go*.

Comment: Notice that this answer was posted in 2011, thus libcurl doesn't support OS X keychain at that time.

Answer (score 10):

"New" `curl` on Mac OS does not "look" at system Keychain database (old curl versions worked great with `-E` option).

You can still make it work with `curl` on newer versions of Mac OS:

```
brew install curl
```

(installs version of curl that works with Client Certificates read from Keychain)

and then something like:

```
/usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl -E wlad https://mail.securedbyclientcertificate.com/access/
```

(in `-E` you type name of your client certificate in Keychain database)

Mac OS will ask you for permission to read from Keychain, type your MacOS password and select "Always Allow"..

Comment: phew! that was quite helpful.

Comment: I'm on a new Macbook with macOS 10.15.5. I have MacPorts, but using the 'native' ver of `curl`. When I try to d/l the latest `youtube-dl`: `sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`, I get a cert expired error. he youtube-dl maintainers say their cert is valid & up-to-date. How can I fix this?

Comment: Even the latest version in `brew install curl` doesnt support reading from keychain. I had to installed to a specific version to make it work. documenting it here in case someone really needs it. `brew extract --version=7.69 curl homebrew/cask` and `brew install curl@7.69`

Comment: We can specify certificate like `    CURL_CA_BUNDLE=./cacert.pem curl 'https://local.io/'` For more, see https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 5):

In current versions of MacOS you can tell the system installed `curl` to use the Keychain using the `CURL_SSL_BACKEND` environment variable e.g. to use a named client cert from the Keychain (it will pop up a Keychain authentication dialogue):

```
CURL_SSL_BACKEND=secure-transport curl --cert "My Cert" htps://10.0.1.101/
```